# JHipster and HIVE integration

Tags: mysql, hive, integration, jhipster

I am trying to connect JHipster's MySQL database with a HIVE database so that JHipster can be receive data from HIVE tables. I want to ask you what is the best approach for this problem as I have just began using JHipster.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

what do you mean when you say *JHipster's MySQL database with a HIVE database*? I asume that you want to use the MySQL database for authentification and authorization and then for diferent bussines logic you will want to retrive data from HIVE. If you are using your JHipster project with a relational database, then jhipster is using [spring data jpa](http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-jpa/) in order to access the database. Since HIVE is a NoSQL database, my recomandation it will be to have a look at [spring-hadoop](http://projects.spring.io/spring-hadoop/) for an easy access on HIVE database and create a service which is macking use of sopring-data-jpa.

Comment: Well ... the idea is to totally change the database JHipster is using and to plug it with a HIVE database ... replicating the user authentication tables within HIIVE in order for JHipster to only use the HIVE DB. Thank you very much, I'll try what you said.

Comment: Actually what I need is not a way of connecting to Apache Hadoop ... but rather a way of changing JHipster's liquibase connection to HIVE connection parameters.

Comment: JHipster supports Casandra and MongoDB as nosql database. You can generate a JHipster app using one of the nosql database and have a look there if you can migrate to HIVE.

Comment: I need to connect to HIVE as it were an SQL database. Through JDBC. I have   actually made it with a simple JAVA program using the _JDBC Client Sample Code_ from here: https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer2+Clients#HiveServer2Clients-JDBC